# Ruby, which exception is best to handle unset environment variables?

Tags: ruby, shell, environment

The script I wrote runs at start up and requires that an environment variable be set, but which of Ruby's [Exceptions](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Exception.html), is best? I used `LoadError`, I just want to be as descriptive as possible and follow the proper conventions.

Secondly, I can't find another way to see if an environment variable is set besides checking it's length, but that doesn't seem so elegant.

```
begin
  raise LoadError if ENV['FOO'].to_s.length == 0
  system "open http://example.com/" + ENV['FOO']
rescue Exception => e
  puts "=> #{e} FOO environment variable not set"
end
```

Comment: any reason to not just write your own exception?

Comment: Because I'd rather follow a convention that is more popular if it's available to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could use [ENV.fetch('FOO')](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/ENV.html#method-c-fetch) which then raises a KeyError if not found.

Comment: This is the most simple and straight forward, since 2012 things have changed and this seems to have emerged as a popular design pattern.

Answer (score 14):

You can do something like:

```
ENV['SECRET_KEY_XXYY'] || raise('no SECRET_KEY_XXYY provided')
```

Answer (score 8):

According to the [documentation for LoadError](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/LoadError.html) that is supposed to be used for when a 'require' has an issue. I think the more proper method would be to subclass `StandardError` and make one that fits your use. If that seems a bit much I would just go with `StandardError` with a descriptive message.

Answer (score 3):

Making your own exceptions is easy:

```
MyError = Class.new(StandardError)
raise MyError, "FOO environment variable not set" unless ENV['FOO']
system "open http://example.com/" + ENV['FOO']
```

Catching the exception in that code block may not be appropriate in this case, since it seems you are just printing a message with it.  As a rule, never raise an exception unless you are prepared for it to terminate the program.  In other words, avoid using exceptions for expected conditions.  If the program can continue without FOO being set, it would be better to simply make execution of the system statement conditional:

```
system("open http://example.com/" + ENV['FOO']) if ENV['FOO']
```

or

```
ENV['FOO'] && system("open http://example.com/" + ENV['FOO'])
```

Answer (score 3):

There's a list of exception types at http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/projects/ruby/wiki/ExceptionClassesDoc

I'd probably choose ArgumentError , as you're saying that the value of `ENV['FOO']` isn't what you expected it to be.

Answer (score 1):

You could use fetch with a block to raise specific error

```rb
ENV.fetch('FOO') { raise 'FOO environment variable is not set' }
```